# AngularJS $http error function never called

Tags: angularjs

I have that simple code :

```
$http.get("/api/test")
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("error");
        return status;
});
```

It works fine, but the error function is never called, even when I return a 404 (Not Found) from the server...
In that case it calls that 'success' function with status = 404...

Is that correct?

Thanks

Fiddler:

```
Request

GET http://localhost:41234/api/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:41234
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22
Referer: http://localhost:41234/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=bd1b3rib5j4beub0xbuhb1hm; FormsAuthentication=xxxxx

Response

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUGVzc29hxvY2FyLkFwaVxhcGcg==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your webserver, it is setting content-length to 0 that means that is a valid value as you can see on [HTTP/1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13).

Also I made a example on JSFiddle showing the error and success examples. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/danielcsgomes/cAMc6/1/).

The headers from the error example:

Request:

```
GET /error/ HTTP/1.1
Host: fiddle.jshell.net
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like  Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31
DNT: 1
Referer: http://fiddle.jshell.net/danielcsgomes/cAMc6/1/show/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: UTF-8,*;q=0.5
Cookie: csrftoken=4tNVNxC5v6BSq9yJCKkHlGFJBz3cClqd`
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
Server: nginx/0.8.54
Date: Fri, 12 Apr 2013 00:38:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Angularjs doesn't care what the content-length is.

Comment: This answer should not be marked as right, it's actually wrong like AgDude mentioned. For me the right answer was the one from @wilver (see below)!

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem and, honestly, follow the hints of this post put me in the wrong direction...
so, I share my case/solution so other in my same situation could save time.

I'm using Angular.js 1.2.14 + WebApi 2. 
this my response for a NotFound status:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:0
Date:Sat, 15 Mar 2014 14:28:35 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcU3ZpbHVwcG9EaXNjaXR1clxhcGlcTWFnMTRcYXBpXGxlc3Nvblw4NA==?=
```

As you can see, Content-Lenght:0, but that's ok.

My problem was the uncorrect use of Angular.js interceptor, in particular something like this:

```
responseError: function (result) {
                // check something 
                return result;
            }
```

returning result without throw an exception or rejecting the promises ([as written in docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)) makes Angular believe that I want to convert rejection in correct resolution and, after that, success callback is called.

I correct my code as follow:

```
responseError: function (result) {                    
                // check something 
                return $q.reject(result);
            }
```

Comment: Same in my case. This is more useful than the selected answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using AngularJS version 1.1.1 or greater...

Does appending '.json' work?:

```
$http.get("/api/test.json")
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
  }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("error");
      return status;
});
```

If so, it can also be fixed with:

```
myModule.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

See this => [Angular JS Fails After Upgrade from 1.1.0 to 1.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811062/angular-js-fails-after-upgrade-from-1-1-0-to-1-1-1)

Comment: Hello, appending .json is generating that error: {"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:4021/api/test.json'.","messageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'user.json'."} ... I´m using .NET Web API on server...

Comment: I added the fiddler request/response to question

Comment: why would changing the extension help in this particular situation... I don't see it

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little on late but... At the moment Angular $http request give you a premise so you can change it to:

```
$http({
    method: "yourMethod",
    url: "yourUrl",
    data: {yourDataObj}
}).then(function (res) {     //first function "success"
    console.log(res.data);
}, function (err) {          //second function "error"
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We moved the post to a factory, we don't really care here about testing the $http stuff, just what it does on success or error:

```
factoryModule.factory('GiftFactory', function ($http, Settings) {
    var saveUrl = Settings.endpoints.saveUrl;

    return {
        createGift: function (data) {
            var gift = { gift: JSON.stringify(angular.toJson(data.gift)) };
            return $http.post(saveUrl, gift);
        }
    };
});
```

We call it like this:

```
    $scope.submit = function () {
        $scope.submitting = true;
        GiftFactory.createGift($scope)
            .success(function () {
                $window.location = Giving.endpoints.indexUrl;
            }).error(function() {
                $scope.submitting = false;
                alert('an error occurred');
        });
    };
```

We test it like this:

```
describe('donation controller', function () {
var $scope, q, window, controller;

beforeEach(module('giving.donation'));
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $q) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    window = {};
    q = $q;
    giftFactory = {};
    controller = $controller('DonationController', { $scope: $scope, $window: window, GiftFactory: giftFactory });
}));

describe('submit', function () {
    var deferred;
    beforeEach(function () {
        deferred = q.defer();

        deferred.promise.success = function (fn) {
            deferred.promise.then(
                function (response) {
                    fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
        deferred.promise.error = function (fn) {
            deferred.promise.then(null,
                function (response) {
                    fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
    });

    it('should redirect on success', function () {
        //Arrange
        Giving = { endpoints: { indexUrl: "/testurl" } };

        giftFactory.createGift = function () {
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        //Act
        $scope.submit();

        deferred.resolve({});
        $scope.$apply();

        //Assert
        expect($scope.submitting).toBeTruthy();
        expect(window.location).toBe('/testurl');
    });

    it('should set submitting back to false on error', function () {
        //Arrange
        Giving = { endpoints: { indexUrl: "/testurl" } };

        giftFactory.createGift = function () {
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        //Act
        $scope.submit();

        deferred.reject({});
        $scope.$apply();

        //Assert
        expect($scope.submitting).toBeFalsy();
        expect(window.location).toBeUndefined();
    });
});

});
```