# Angular since 1.1.1 returned resource hash as separate symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-resource

In stable 1.0.7 version all is working perfectly:

Here is my resource (with Rails as backend):

```
app.factory "Post", ($resource, apiPrefix) ->
  $resource( apiPrefix + "/posts/:id",
    id: "@id"
  ,
    update:
      method: "PUT"
  )
```

And in all queries it return completely correct hashes.

But when I tried to install version newer than 1.1.0, resource begins to returned hash like this:

```
post:  { 
    0: <
    1: !
    2: D
    3: O
    4: C
    5: T
    6: Y
    7: P
    8: E
    ...
```

So, the question is - Why?

Comment: Looks like isArray might be true by default? Just a guess

Comment: It looks like the rails API is not returning JSON but HTML (`<!DOCTYPE...`). Maybe an HTML error page? Is your request still correct?

Answer (score 0):

So, problem is done, according [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811062/angular-js-fails-after-upgrade-from-1-1-0-to-1-1-1):

since 1.1.1 version, angular need ".json" affix in each resource url:

```
app.factory "Post", ($resource, apiPrefix) ->
  $resource( apiPrefix + "/posts/:id.json",
    id: "@id"
  ,
    update:
      method: "PUT"
  )
```