# angular $http.get does not get json respond_to from rails (without tweaking headers)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am using angularjs on a rails app.  I'd like to make a search form that paginates server side data.

Here is my form:

`<input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search Products" ng-model="search_terms" />`

My rails controller accepts either json or html requests:

```
def index
  # ....
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {
      # ...
    }
    format.html {
      # ...
    }
  end
end
```

And here is my angular controller.  For some reason the $http service was only able to get back the rails default html response and not the json response.

```
$scope.$watch('search_terms',function(newValue,oldValue){
  var query = newValue;

  $http.get('/products',{params:{search_terms:query}, responseType:'json'}).success(function(data) {
  // do something
  });

});
```

If I use this jQuery.get I DO get back the desired json response, so why does angular give me html?

```
  jQuery.get('/products',{search_terms:query},function(data){
     console.log(data);
  }, 'json')
```

I checked the network headers and the main difference between the angular call and the jQuery call is that angular does not set X-Requested-With header to 'XMLHttpRequest'?

If I add that then I can get it to work.

```
 $http.get('/products',{params:{search_terms:query}, responseType:'json', 'headers':{'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'}}).success(function(data) {
  // do something
  });
```

But being new to Angular I don't know if this is the right fix for this problem.  Feels sort of clunky to have to do this each time.  Is there a better way or this is just how you do it if using Angular and Rails?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular JS Fails After Upgrade from 1.1.0 to 1.1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811062/angular-js-fails-after-upgrade-from-1-1-0-to-1-1-1)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1004

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same thing and got frustrated by it. My first solution was a bit of a cop out, I ended up going with this gem:

https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource

But after having a bit more experience, I discovered it has to do with angular not setting the right headers.

```javascript
angular.module('yourmodule').run(['$http', function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
}]);
```

reference: http://angulartutorial.blogspot.com/2014/05/set-headers-for-all-http-calls-in.html

Keep in mind the situation also exists for request.xhr

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16444